# Rails Can't mass-assign protected attributes error when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `business` model which has_one `address` and I am trying to build a form that accepts address attributes when the business is being created. I am getting error

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address

Here are my models

**Business**

```
class Business<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :address_attributes, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :address
  validates_associated :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**Address**

```
class Address<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :line1, :city, :zip
  validates_presence_of :line1, :city, :zip

  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**View**

```
%h2 Sign up
= form_for(:business, :url => business_registration_path) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :name
    %br/
    = f.text_field :name
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  %div
    =f.fields_for :address do |address|
      =render :partial => 'businesses/shared/address', :locals => {:f => address}
  %div= f.submit "Sign up"
= render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

**Partial view**

```
%div
  = f.label :line1, 'Address 1'
  %br/
  =f.text_field :line1
%div
  = f.label :city
  %br/
  = f.text_field :city
%div
  = f.label :zip, 'Postal Code'
  %br/
  = f.text_field :zip
```

**Raw POST Data THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/h17NgMDr4VCTDd+FxGlAI4RWmfAat9guU9q00hYIA4=", "business"=>{"name"=>"hello", "email"=>"hello@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "address"=>{"line1"=>"this is line1",  "city"=>"Andra", "country"=>"Jama", "zip"=>"123123"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

shouldn't the address fields go like this

```
"address_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"this is line1",  "city"=>"Andra", "country"=>"Jama", "zip"=>"123123"}
```

Why is it generating address instead of address_attributes ? This might be causing the issue. Any ideas? I have been struggling with this for about 2 hours. Appreciated any suggestions or solutions.

**Upadte1:**

If I make a change in the view and use

```
 =f.fields_for :address_attributes do |address|
```

instead of

```
 =f.fields_for :address do |address|
```

Everythings starts working but this isn't what all the tutorials and the docs are talking about ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be passing an object (instance of the `Business` class) to `form_for` rather than a symbol:

```
= form_for(@business, :url => business_registration_path) do |f|
```

Presumably, you will have `@business = Business.new` in the controller action.

The `Business` class contains all the validation and association logic. Use a symbol when you want a modeless form (Rails does not infer that `:business` refers to the `Business` class, even if they share the same name).

Comment: Well this works, but i don't understand why, what difference does it make to pass a symbol or the actual object ? if you can elaborate a bit it would be great.. but anyway thanks for the solution it works :)

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the fact that there is logic attached to the class that only comes into play when you have an instance--specifically to manage the behavior or accepts_nested_attributes_for. if you don't have an instance you don't have that behavior...